# Keep resource file on root level in repackaged JAR file

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, dependencies

I'm using the Spring Boot Maven Plugin in my pom.xml and more precisely the **repackage** goal to create an executable jar: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.1.RELEASE/maven-plugin/examples/repackage-classifier.html

This moves all application classes under `BOOT-INF/classes` in the JAR file.

In my case I have a file under my `src/main/resources` path, let's say it's `src/main/resources/my-file.txt`.

In a normal JAR file the above `my-file.txt` would be placed at root level in the JAR.
When I repackage the JAR however, the file goes to `BOOT-INF/classes/my-file.txt`. This is a problem for me as I really need this file on root level in the JAR.

Is there a way to achieve what I'm looking for with maven somehow as I don't want to have to manually insert the file on root level into the JAR with a command afterwards?

Thanks!

Comment: How you're accessing your file in .java after creating the jar?

Comment: The jar file is deployed to a cloud environment later.

Comment: Somewhere in your java class, you wrote the code to fetch/read the resource file right? I am asking may know the statement which you wrote to access the file from the resource.

Comment: First I would suggest to use a more recent version of Spring Boot. Furthermore the location of the resources in Spring Boot is correct cause a spring boot jar works different than a usual jar...and yes it would be helpful to see the code you are using to access the resources..